# How to use GetIpInterfaceEntry on win7+vs2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, routetable

I'm trying to add some rule to the route table with **CreateIpForwardEntry**, it's necessary to call the **GetIpInterfaceEntry** first on win7(see [this](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=74)). Here's part of my code:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x601

//#define _WS2IPDEF_
//#define __IPHLPAPI_H__

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <netioapi.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

int main() {
    typedef DWORD(__stdcall *IPINTENTRY)(PMIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW);// undeclared identifier
    MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW info;
    info.InterfaceIndex = 1;
    memset(&(info.InterfaceLuid),0,sizeof(info.InterfaceLuid));
    info.Family = AF_INET;
    HINSTANCE hInst = ::LoadLibrary("Iphlpapi.dll");
    IPINTENTRY pFunGetInfEntry = (IPINTENTRY)GetProcAddress(hInst,"GetIpInterfaceEntry");
    DWORD dwRet = pFunGetInfEntry(&info);
}
```

the code doesn't compile, **PMIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW** is undeclared identifier, I looked into the windows headers, it's the ***WS2IPDEF*** that controls the flow. I #defined it but still now working. Anyone has been using this function? Thanks.

Comment: It is not lean anymore, only mean.  And move the #include for winsock2 *before* the one for windows.h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it not compiling, or compiling and not running? To get the code to compile I had to change the includes: I removed

```
#include <netioapi.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
```

and replaced it with

```
#include <ws2def.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
```

following the comments at the top of "netioapi.h".

Comment: Thanks it works after replacing these headers and remove the *_WS2IPDEF_* and *__IPHLPAPI_H__*.

Answer (score 1):

Include the following headers in this order:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2def.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <netioapi.h>
```